# object moving in wrong directions

Tags: java, math

I have a problem with my Java game(2d, top down view)
where my character shoots a bullet in the direction of the mouse.
I tried some code I found here but I'm having a problem.
thebullet only seldom moves in the right direction.
it often moves straigt up, down, left and right.
seen the point that I also had this  problem with other code I tried I don't think that the problem is in this code. any ideas?

```
int deltax = bullet.endpos.x - bullet.startx;//this code is when I create a new bullet
int deltay = bullet.endpos.y - bullet.starty;
direction = Math.atan(deltay / deltax);
speed = 5.0;

bullet.x=(bullet.x - (speed * Math.cos(direction)));
bullet.y=(bullet.y - (speed * Math.sin(direction)));
```

Comment: What is the type of `direction`? Integer arithmetic could result in the vertical/horizontal behaviour. Have you tried running it through a debugger (or setting `println` statements) and seeing what the values are at runtime?

Comment: Since it's being passed to a Math trig function, direction must be a double that expresses the angle in radians.

Comment: Independent on type of `direction` this function would be incorrect as `deltaX / deltaY` is integer division, which is unapplicable here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to know the real angle in this code.

The code should be:

```
int deltaX = bullet.endpos.x - bullet.startx; //this code is when I create a new bullet
int deltaY = bullet.endpos.y - bullet.starty;
double radius = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
double normalizedDeltaX = deltaX / radius;
double normalizedDeltaY = deltaY / radius;
speed = 5.0;

bullet.x -= /*maybe your error is here, and there should be += as you need to increment coordinates, not decrement*/ speed * normalizedDeltaX;
bullet.y -= /*the same thing here*/ speed * normalizedDeltaY;
```

Or if you would really you this angle later (what for?) in this case `Math.atan2` is more appreciated, because you won't lose third and fourth quarters of the plane:

```
double direction = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
```